# DiscordJs v13 - DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body attachments[0].id: This field is required

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a welcome image using [Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas), whenever a user joins the guild. I get a DiscordAPIError when the code runs.

This is my code:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
        const { guild } = member

        const channelId = getChannelId(guild.id)
        if(!channelId){
            return
        }

        const welcomeChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        if(!welcomeChannel) {
            return
        }

        const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        const background = await Canvas.loadImage(
            path.join(__dirname, '../utilities/background.png')
        )

        let x = 0
        let y = 0
        ctx.drawImage(background, x, y)

        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome.png')

        console.log(attachment)

        welcomeChannel.send({
            content: `Welcome <@${member.user.id}>! Enjoy in ${guild.name}`,
            attachments: [attachment]
        })
    })
```

I get this error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
attachments[0].id: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Samyak\Codes\DiscordJS.TS\Music\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Samyak\Codes\DiscordJS.TS\Music\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Samyak\Codes\DiscordJS.TS\Music\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Samyak\Codes\DiscordJS.TS\Music\features\welcome.js:61:13) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/903164915689328683/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: "Welcome <@737910447486926849>! Enjoy in MatterHorn2006's server",
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: [Array],
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

According to this error, there is no **id** property to the attachment I am sending.

So, is there a problem with my code or there's a problem with the DiscordJs?

Comment: Try to use `files: ['path_to_file/file']` instead of `attachments`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same exact error but fixed it by doing

> ```
>  welcomeChannel.send({
>  content: `Welcome <@${member.user.id}>! Enjoy in ${guild.name}`,
>  files: [new MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome.png')]
>  })
> ```